# Conditionals in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

So I'd like to add a class if a condition is met.I've added a ng-class and I'd like to add a class when the value reaches 100. Here is a look at my directive. I know this is possible with ng-class I just forgot how to implement this.

```js
angular.directive 'atomProgressbar', ($patterns, $atomicService) ->
  template: """
  <progress ng-class="{'progress-100: progress.value == 100'}" id='progress-bar' max='100' value='50'></progress>
  """
  scope: $patterns.NGBindings(pattern.bindings)
  link: ($scope) ->
    $atomicService.processBindings(pattern, $scope)

# EXAMPLE ->
# %atom-progress{:max => "100", :value => "0"}

export default pattern
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just have a syntax error, and it should instead be `ng-class="{'progress-100': progress.value == 100}"`.

Comment: Thank you for catching my syntax error. I tried using this method `ng-class="{'progress-100': progress.value == 100}"` I also tried `ng-class="{'progress-100': progress.value === '100'}"` and that isn't working either

Answer (score 1):

You are setting progress value to 50 and then in ng-class the progress value is 100. The value has to be bound to a scope variable. Since I dont have your JS code, I am assuming this is your actual code. I created a plunker to demonstrate that its working fine with the correct syntax. If it's still not working, We will need to see the complete code to find out where its going wrong. Do you see the "progress-100" class added when you inspect the element?

http://plnkr.co/edit/11v47PalZgn7vIOKLfFR?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
     <progress ng-class="{'progress-100':value == 100}" id='progress-bar' max='100' value={{value}}></progress>

  </body>
```

Comment: I started a new thread with updated code. I have everything in place.  But I think it needs to be triggered in a link function